# Regex/Input Filter for android to prevent more than one leading zero

Tags: java, android, regex, android-input-filter, input-filter

I'm looking for some help to get a regex for Android, that prevents more that one leading zero in a given decimal number. Currently, any number of zeros can be added before the actual digit. I'm looking for the support of numbers like 0.1, 11.04, 0129 . The numbers that should not be allowed are .9, 0009999.33, 0007

Existing Filter Class, is given below :

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter{

Pattern mPattern;
int maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint = 10;
int maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint = 2;

public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero, int digitsAfterZero)
{
    this.maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint = digitsBeforeZero;
    this.maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint = digitsAfterZero;
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart,
        int dend)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
    builder.replace(dstart, dend, source.subSequence(start, end).toString());
    if(!builder.toString().matches(
            "(([0-9]{1})([0-9]{0," + (maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint - 1) + "})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0,"
                    + maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint + "})?"))
    {
        if(source.length() == 0)
            return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
        return "";
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like this `^\\..*|^[0]{2,}.*` ?

Comment: see [here](http://pastebin.com/WchkxhgD)

Answer (score 0):

The regex that allows a float/integer number without 2 or more leading zeros:

```
^(?!0{2,})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP8vX4/3)

Actually, it is suffice to check for just 2 `0`s in the beginning (although it is just a matter of taste):

```
^(?!0{2})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
       ^
```

In Android, you can use the following regex declaration with `matches()`:

```
String pattrn = "^(?!0{2,})\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?";
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pP8Weo)

The regex breakdown:

- `^(?!0{2,})` - at the beginning, checks if the next symbols are not 2 or more `0`s
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\\.\\d+)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of

  - `\\.` - a literal period
  - `\\d+` - 1 or more digits